# How to call css styles in specific page in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have creating webpage in angular. i have three stylesheets. these three files are called in all pages. Now, I want to execute specific CSS block for my home page. I tried less file for this process.

**HTML:**

// This code for home page

```
<div class="homePage">
<div class="content">

</div>
</div>
```

//This code for inner page

```
<div class="content">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.homePage
{
    .content
    {
        background-color: #F00;
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
.content
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

But its not working. please help me.

Comment: You are aware that you need to transform LESS to CSS before the browser can use it?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @connexo. I don't have knowledge about lesstocss transform. Please help me for how to do it..?

Comment: How is it not working? What does the style inspector show?

Comment: Browsers do not understand LESS, only CSS. Koala is for example an app that translates it. http://koala-app.com/ Also make sure you understand how it works. Go to http://less-css.org

Comment: @torazaburo Showing without property and value. like this (".homePage{ }").

Comment: That's expected, because you have defined no styles on `.homePage`. What does the style inspector show for `.content`?

Comment: showing this (.content
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a global style for `.content` div

```
.content {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Whenever you want to override the `.content` div style or add page specific style, simply just wrap `.content` div into a parent div

### HTML

```
<div class="home-page">
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.home-page .content {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```